# Poisson (joint) pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Lad $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. with the distribution $\mathcal{Poiss}(\lambda)$, for $\lambda>0$.

- Write the joint pdf $(X_1,...,X_n)$ and argue that for $$P((X_1,..,X_n) \in \left \{ 0,1,2,..., \right \}^n)=1$$

for a fixed $(x_1,...,x_n) \in \left \{ 0,1,2,..., \right \}^n$

**Concerns**

I am unsure on what I am even asked to show. I get the Poisson distribution definition and the support of it. But I am not sure on what is asked to show to even begin to show it is indeed equal to $1$. I can probably do the calculations and manipulation when I get it in another form.

Comment: Note: The joint distribution is discrete; it will not have a *probability density function* (pdf).  Rather it shall have a *probability mass function* (pmf).

Comment: @GrahamKemp This is just taken directly from my problem assigned. But yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

The probability mass function of a vector of random variables will equal the joint probability mass function of the random variables.

The joint probability mass function of *independent* random variables shall be the product of the probability mass functions of those random variables.

The probability mass functions of *identically distributed* random variables are identical, and these are a Poisson distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda$.

So....

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\langle X_1,\ldots,X_n\rangle{=}\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n\rangle) ~&=~ \mathsf P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n( X_i{=}x_i)\right)\\&=~ \prod_{i=1}^n \mathsf P(X_i{=}x_i)\\[0ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: $p_{\mathbf X}(\mathbf x) = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}
= e^{-n\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{\sum_i x_i}}{x_1!x_2!\cdots x_n!}.$ is my thought but this seem somewhat impossible to show equal to 1?

Comment: You wish to show $\mathsf P(\mathbf X\in\{0,1,\ldots\}^n)=1$.  Begin by arguing:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\mathbf X\in\{0,1,\ldots\}^n)&=\mathsf P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (X_i\in\{0,1,...\}))\\&=\mathsf P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\bigcup_{x_i=0}^\infty (X_i=x_i))\end{align}$$

Comment: So my expression is wrong.

Comment: No, your expression is correct, @mathstudent23 $$\begin{align}p_{\small\mathbf X}(\mathbf x)&=\mathsf P(\mathbf X{=}\mathbf x) \\[2ex]&=\left.\mathrm e^{-n\lambda}\lambda^{\raise{1ex}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}}\middle/(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i!)\right.\end{align}$$ It is just that *that* is not what you want to equal $1$, but rather the series for *all* supported $\mathbf x$ should equal $1$. (re: the Law of Total Probability). $$\sum_{\mathbf x\in\{0,1,...\}^n}p_{\small\mathbf X}(\mathbf x)=1$$

Comment: Ok now I am following this! I guess the sum of the product seems really tough to show equal to 1.